# Is it possible to run fbi inside tmux if the tmux if running in a virtual tty?

Tags: tmux, fbi

I have already looked at [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/387678/how-to-enable-display-of-framebuffer-images-e-g-in-w3m-fbi-within-byobu-pts/411721#411721) and the solution works insofar as I can get an image displayed in my virtual console. However, if I first launch a `tmux` inside the virtual console, and then try `fbi <imagename>`, this fails with the following error.

```
using "DejaVu Sans Mono-16", pixelsize=16.67 file=/usr/share/fonts/truetype/dejavu/DejaVuSansMono.ttf
ioctl VT_GETSTATE: Inappropriate ioctl for device (not a linux console?)
```

Is there a workaround for this, such as some setting for `tmux` that will allow it to work with `fbi`?

Comment: I know this is quite old but did you ever find a solution to this? I've seen different sites that say it's impossible but then I also see others that talk as though it is possible.

Comment: @Rick, Nope I didn't find a solution.

Comment: Per fbi man page:  fbi  also  needs  access to the linux console (i.e. /dev/ttyN) for sane
       console switch handling.  That is  obviously  no  problem  for  console
       logins, but any kind of a pseudo tty (xterm, ssh, screen, ...) will not
       work.
So it probably won't work

Comment: Note: fbi-improved (fim) works ok inside tmux. Mutt inside tmux, viewing attached images with ~/.mailcap: "Image/JPEG;fim %s", also tested - ok.

Answer (score 3):

Run `fbi -vt 1 <imagename>` with root privilege. It will show the image in console 1 which is activated by <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>F1</kbd>.

`openvt -c 1 -f fbi <imagename>` would also do the trick. But my test result shows that the console openvt occupied would restart after fbi finished.